# Add SKU in Woocommerce Checkout and Order received Urls

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, query-string, checkout

In woocommerce, we allow to buy only one product at the time on our shop. We have very few products and no shop page (or archives pages). Quantity fields are disabled and customer is redirected to checkout on add to cart.

We need to customize some URLs to detect what has been added to cart (what has been bought). So I would need to propagate the product SKU Checkout and Order received URLs.

I was able, for example, to add the SKU in the THANK YOU URL with this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url','override_return_url',10,2);
function override_return_url($return_url,$order){

    // create empty array to store url parameters in 
    $sku_list = array();

    // retrieve products in order
    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item)
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);

        // get sku of each product and insert it in array 
        $sku_list['product_'.$item['product_id'] .'sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    // build query strings out of the SKU array
    $url_extension = http_build_query($sku_list);

    // append our strings to original url
    $modified_url = $return_url.'&'.$url_extension;

    return $modified_url;

  }
```

But I need the SKU in the checkout URL too.

For information I have multiple kinds of Add to cart buttons on a product page:

- The woocommerce default one.
- Some others in the product content using Shortcode like `[add_to_cart id="99"]`
- one last using [Sticky add to cart for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-add-to-cart-for-woocommerce/) plugin.

Is it possible? How should I do?

Comment: Noone? Is my question clear? Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is a bit outdated** since Woocommerce 3… Instead you should use the following code.

You will have to disable any add to cart redirection by settings or by code. You will have to remove all your related code to avoid errors or malfunctions.

The code:

```
// Redirect to checkout on add to cart and append the sku to the url
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', 'add_to_cart_sku_to_url', 20, 1 );
function add_to_cart_sku_to_url( $product_permalink ) {
    global $product;

    if( $product->get_sku() ) {
        return add_query_arg( ￼'sku', $product->get_sku(), wc_get_checkout_url() );
    }
    return $product_permalink;
}

// Order received: Append the product sku to the URL
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url', 'add_product_sku_to_return_url', 20, 2 );
function add_product_sku_to_return_url( $return_url, $order  ) {
    $items   = $order->get_items();
    $item    = reset($items);
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $sku      = $product->get_sku();

    if( ! empty($sku) )
        $return_url = add_query_arg( ￼'sku', $sku, $return_url );

    return $return_url;
}

// Add to cart shortcode ( Product ID is not needed )
if( ! function_exists('get_custom_add_to_cart') ) {
    function get_custom_add_to_cart( ) {
        if ( ! is_product() ) return;

        ob_start();

        global $product, $post;

        if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Order' ) )
            $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->get_type() . '_add_to_cart' );

        return ob_get_clean();

    }
    add_shortcode( 'custom_add_to_cart', 'get_custom_add_to_cart' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

---

Specifically for your plugin you should also add this code:

```
// Redirect GET add to cart to checkout apending sku as query arg
add_action('template_redirect', 'get_add_to_cart_sku_to_checkout');
function get_add_to_cart_sku_to_checkout() {
    // Not on checkout page
    if( ( is_product() || is_404() ) && isset($_GET['add-to-cart']) ){
        $product_id = (int) $_GET['add-to-cart']; // Checkout Url
        if( $product_id > 0 ){
            $sku = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', true );
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( ￼'sku', $sku, wc_get_checkout_url() ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

Comment: Thanks a lot @loic, The "thank you code" works fine. But, what you are saying is that it's not possible to display the SKU in the ADD TO CART / CHECKOUT URLs due to the AJAX calls?

Thing is that advertising platforms need unique URLs to understand which pages the user visited (for example I need to paste URL CONTAINS: [unique-parameter])

There is absolutely no way to do it?

Comment: Hello @loic, I am actually asking for one thing only. Propagate the SKU through the URLs when purchasing a product. Do you think that would be a simpler way to elaborate the question?